# Get an ID from an ASP Label with Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a `<label ID="lblContent">` in a Slideshow like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlResult" runat="server" Visible="false" class="slideshow-container1" style="height:300px;margin-left: 0px;">
<asp:DataList  ID="dlResults" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlResults_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <div class="mySlides1>
      <a href="AnotherPage.aspx">
        <asp:Label  ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
      </a>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
    <a class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides1(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next1" onclick="plusSlides1(1)">&#10095;</a>
</asp:Panel>
```

My Web page automatically generates spans with the same id always like this

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlResults_ctl02_lblContent"> bla bla </span>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlResults_ctl01_lblContent"> bla bla </span>
```

Then, we see that the id increments each time `ct101`, `ct102`... when the slideshow works

I want to identify the current id each time because I need to call it in a `href`

Is there a possibility to do this in `JS` or other, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the ItemDataBound event, you can get the ClientId for each label  created, like

```
protected void dlResults_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      Label contentLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblContent");
      someGlobalString += "var contentLabel = document.getElementByID(\"" + contentLabel.ClientId + "\");\r\n";
   }
}
```

You can then use this to create your Javascript dynamically, and inject it to the page, like

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!(Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("MyScript")))
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyScript", someGlobalString, true);
}
```